# FAST Search on user profile propeprties

Tags: 2013, fast-search, sharepoint-search

I have a requirement for FQL search on SharePoint User Profile (SharePoint 2013). I can't use KQL since it doesnt do 'contains' searches.

I created a copy of the 'Local People Results' result source and set the Query Transform  as:

`{?andnot({searchTerms},filter(contentclass:"urn:content-class:SPSPeople*"))}`

Fast search seems to be working.

I set the 'Type' field in the result source as 'SharePoint Search Results' and I am getting results for content in SharePoint site. But the results don't contain people. The query I used is `Author:string("shaju")`.

But I set the Type to 'People Search Results' and don't get any results at all. The query I am using here is `FirstName:string("shaju")`. Firstname is a userprofile property.

I removed the QueryTransform tried a query in KQL(FirstName:shaju) and it works.any ideas on why FAST search is not providing results for people(user profile)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People results are stored in the SharePoint index, not in the FS4SP index. Hence FQL will not work for people queries.

And KQL does do contains. Property:value is contains while Property=value is equals.

Author:Mikael

will return both "Mikael Svenson" as well as "Mr Mikael". Should work for FirstName as well I believe.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mikael. But from my testing, KQL does contains searches when the query contains a full word in the property . So 'FirstName:Mikael' would return both. But 'FirstName:ikae' wouldn't return any results.Do you have any ideas on overcoming this?

Comment: ikae would not work, as it's term by term contains, not letters contained in a word. What you want is pre/postfix wild cards, which is not supported by the SP index afaik.

Comment: You can do suffix wildcards only. Author:Mik* not Author:*ael.

Comment: True.. I meant at the same time :) It's wildcards at the beginning which are not supported.